# Python Anywhere access denied to MySQL database

Tags: python, mysql, django, pythonanywhere

I started to use  [Python Anywhere](http://pythonanywhere.com) today. I created the database MySQL following the instructions. The problem is I can't do a simple manage.py syncdb because I get access denied error for my user 'irgmedeiros' in my mysql database. I can't grant privileges to my user neither create another user with privileges. How to solve it? Couldn't find solution in their forum and I'm waiting a answer from email. Anybody experienced this before?

Comment: Environmental and very specific to PythonAnywhere. I don't think anyone here can help. Also not really a very specific question with errors output and code that fails.

Comment: there is actually a small, but reasonably useful community of pythonanywhere users here on SO. have a look at the tag.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Some possible troubleshooting steps:

- check the server address - `mysql.server`
- double-check the password - is it the same as the one you configured on the pythonanywhere MySQL config screens
- double-check the database name - this follows the format `username$database_name`
- check if you can open a normal mysql console, firstly from the MySQL tab, and then manually in a bash shell with

.

```
mysql -u my_username -h mysql.server -p
```

[edit] - the final solution was:

*** double-check the database name - this follows the format `username$database_name`**

don't forget that `username$` folks!

Comment: All check but the database name i just use 'database_name'. I'm not using 'username$database_name'. But I can't see a connection to the problem because I can log into mysql with the commmand line you provided and by console directly. I'm still looking for a solution to the permission denied problem. Thank you btw for the tips.

Comment: well, that's the problem then. you need to use `username$database_name`.  from the mysql console you can confirm this by doing `use username$database_name`, which will work, whereas `use database_name` will not.

Comment: That's it. Now I can use mysql terminal and use the database from there. Now I'm going to make my application acess the DB. Thank you.

Comment: Yeah, using the `username$database_name` format was the solution for me.

Comment: Using the username$database_name format was the solution for me too. I used to access via PythonAnywhere's Database tab with no problem. mysql -u my_username -h mysql.server -p via Bash console and  username$database_name format finally reestablished my access.